# Nesting json - Play 2.3

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

I'm trying to nest json like this:

```
case class Foo(id:Int, a:String, b:String)

def barJson =
  Json.obj("hello" -> "hi")

def getFooJson =
  Json.obj {
    "foos" -> Json.arr {
      fooTable.list.map { foo =>
        Json.toJson(foo) + barJson
      }
    }
  }
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : play.api.libs.json.JsObject
[error]  required: String
```

What am I doing wrong here & how can I fix it? The result I'm going after is something like this:

```
"foos":[
    {
      "a":"hi", 
      "b":"bye", 
      "bar": {
        "hello": "bye"
      }
    }, 
    {
      "a":"hi2", 
      "b":"bye2", 
      "bar": {
        "hello": "bye"
      }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `+` method for adding fields is on `JsObject`, and `Json.toJson(foo)` is only a `JsValue`. If you're sure your `Writes` for `Foo` always produces an object, you can use `.as[JsObject]`:

```
def getFooJson =
  Json.obj {
    "foos" -> Json.arr {
      fooTable.list.map { foo =>
        Json.toJson(foo).as[JsObject] + ("bar" -> barJson)
      }
    }
  }
```

Note also that you need to provide a key-value pair to `+` if you want the JSON in your expected result.

For what it's worth, I'd probably write something like the following:

```
val fooTableWrites = Writes.list(
  JsPath.write[Foo].transform(_.as[JsObject] + ("bar" -> barJson))
).transform(arr => Json.obj("foos" -> arr))

def getFooJson = fooTableWrites.writes(fooTable.list)
```

Does the same thing but you have more nicely composable pieces.

Comment: Is there a way to nest a Json.obj within that nest? `Json.toJson(foo).as[JsObject] + ("bar" -> Json.toJson(foo).as[JsObject] + ("anotherFoo" -> Json.toJson(foo2)))`

Comment: That should work but you may need an extra set of parentheses.